# How to post textbox value after selecting particular checkbox

Tags: php, html

Here is the snippet of html code.....

1)After checking each check box the value's is posting to the database.

2)But the problem is when i checked  **other**, i need to take the value of the text box and it is posting the value of the checkbox instead of the textbox value

but i don't know where i did mistake...

```
<form action="purchase.php" name="form1" id="form1" method="POST">
    <ul class="n_ul"> <span>*</span>
What is your Primary goal?
        <br>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input name="goal" id="goal" value="Add a popular customer service to attract/retain more customers"
            type="checkbox">
        </li> <span>*</span>
Popular customer Services
        <br>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input name="goal" id="goal" value="Add a turnkey revenue sources for my location(s)"
            type="checkbox">
        </li> <span>*</span>
trunkey revenue source
        <br>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input name="goal" id="goal" type="checkbox" value="other">
        </li> <span>*</span>
Other (Please specify below)
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="other" id="goal" type="text" class="new">
    </ul>
   <input type="submit" name=submit value="submit">
</form>
```

Any suggestions are acceptable....

Comment: Not an answer but you should make sure all your id's are unique. However it is ok to have name repeated across elements. Post some php code from purchase.php

Comment: can you var_dump your POST global and show us it's content ?
var_dump($_POST);
Logically the content is located in $_POST['other']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
$_POST['goal'] = ($_POST['goal']=='other') ? $_POST['other'] : $_POST['goal'];
```

This will overwrite the value of goal with the value of other only when the 'other' radio is ticked

Also id attributes of html elements should be unique on the page

**EDIT**

Your question is a little vague. It seems like you may want the form to submit when a checkbox button is clicked.

- If this is the case the other field will be unlikely to be filled as the form will often be submitted before the user gets to populate it
- Try adding a button or input to submit the form

Like this

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: But the textbox value is not posting... Just it taking the value of the other check box value

Comment: How are you submitting your form, do you have a button? or are you pressing enter, or do you have javascript to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of your checkbox, and if it equals to other, you can grab your value from textbox. Do it following way:

```
if (isset($_POST['goal']) && $_POST['goal'] == 'other')
{
    // do something with $_POST['other']
}
```

Comment: But those are check box group...so what can i do?

Comment: Okay, then you could do something like this `if (isset($_POST['goal']) && $_POST['goal'] == 'other']) { DO SOMETHING WITH $_POST['other'] }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="" name="form1" id="form1" method="POST">
    <ul class="n_ul"> <span>*</span>
What is your Primary goal?
        <br>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input name="goal[]" id="goal" value="Add a popular customer service to attract/retain more customers"
            type="checkbox">
        </li> <span>*</span>
Popular customer Services
        <br>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input name="goal[]" id="goal" value="Add a turnkey revenue sources for my location(s)"
            type="checkbox">
        </li> <span>*</span>
trunkey revenue source
        <br>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input name="goal[]" id="goal" type="checkbox" value="other">
        </li> <span>*</span>
Other (Please specify below)
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="other" id="goal" type="text" class="new">
    </ul>
   <input type="submit" name=submit value="submit">
</form>
<?php
$other="";
$goal=$_REQUEST['goal'];
if(in_array("other", $goal)){
$other=$_REQUEST['other'];
}
echo $other;
?>
```